# Firebug like tool for WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, firebug, snoop

I'd like to run my program and hover on elements and have a program show me in the visual tree what I am hovering. I tried 'Snoop' but it just shows me a visual tree without the ability of actually hovering on the elements at runtime. Do you guys know of such a tool?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can do it with Snoop - hover elements at runtime, just click ctrl+shift while hovering with the mouse.

Comment: yeah, weired that it's not documented :)